# Example of $f(x)-f(y)=g(x-y)$

Tags: examples-counterexamples, functional-equations

we know that for linear function $f(x)-f(y)=f(x-y)$ for all $x, y\in D$.

Now, I am wondering, if we replace the $f$ in the right hand side of the equality by some nonlinear $g$, are there any other nonlinear example $f$ such that

for any $x$ and $y$ in the domain, there exists a function $g$:

$f(x)-f(y)=g(x-y)$ for all $x, y\in D$ for some $g$

Thank you

Comment: By shifting $D$ if necessary, we may assume that $0\in D$.  Let $k:=f(0)$.  Then, by setting $y:=0$, we have
$$g(x)=g(x-0)=f(x)-f(0)=f(x)-k\text{ for all }x\in D\,.$$
That is,
$$f(x)=g(x)+k\text{ for all }x\in D\,.$$
Thus, the required functional equation becomes
$$g(x)-g(y)=\big(f(x)-k\big)-\big(f(y)-k\big)=f(x)-f(y)=g(x-y)\text{ for }x,y\in D\,.$$
This looks like Cauchy's functional equation for $g$, but since $D$ might not be the whole $\mathbb{R}$, I am unsure of what all solutions $g$ look like.  And the domain of $g$ seems to be $D-D$.

Comment: $g(x) = f(x) - f(0)$ and $g(y) = f(0) - f(-y)$ so $g(x) + g(y) = f(x) - f(-y) = g(x+y)$ so $g$ satisfies [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation)

Comment: If $f,g$ are continuous at even one point, the only possibility is that they are linear on $D$. Without an additional assumption that will imply continuity, there are infinitely many possibilities, all of which other than the linear case are ill-behaved.

Comment: thank you all for the comment. I get that g can only be linear in this case